# find the records based on search using javascript?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I wrote the below code for finding the records in a table grid.

```
$(function () {

        grid = $('#tblsearchresult');
        // handle search fields key up event
        $('#search-term').keyup(function (e) {
            text = $(this).val(); // grab search term

            if (text.length > 1) {

                // iterate through all grid rows
                grid.find('tr').each(function (i) {

                    if ($(this).find('td:eq(1)').text().toUpperCase().match(text.toUpperCase()))
                        $(this).css({ background: "#A4D3EE" });


                });
            }
            else {
                grid.find('tr:has(td)').css({ background: "" });
                grid.find('tr').show();
            } // if no matching name is found, show all rows
        });

    });



 <table id="tblsearchresult" class="tablesorter"">
            <thead> 
                    <tr>

                        <th>ApplicationName</th>

                  </tr>
            </thead> 

        <tbody>
                <% foreach (var request in Model.ApplicationRoles)
                   { %>
                <tr>

                    <td>
                        <span id="appName_<%: request.Id%>">
                            <%: request.Application.Name%></span>
                    </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

EDIT Table Data

```
  applicationame   role
application1     appadministrator
app              developer
application2      tester
```

if i given 'app'as search text need to highlight secondrow only .highlightling firstrow also because 'app' is there in role of firstrow..exact match should be highlight on every rows.please tell me.

Comment: It would be better if you provide the generated html

Comment: I guess thats the prob with the `.match()`,it actually expects regular exp, so could you change it as `if ($(this).find('td:eq(1)').text().toUpperCase().match("/"+text.toUpperCase()+"/"))
                        $(this).css({ background: "#A4D3EE" });`

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the highlight before you parse. Add this statement of yours:

```
grid.find('tr:has(td)').css({ background: "" });
```

before entering this loop:

```
// iterate through all grid rows
grid.find('tr').each(function (i) {
    ...
});
```

Check this fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/F3jRj/1/**

And this updated fiddle with 3 columns: **http://jsfiddle.net/F3jRj/2/**

Comment: if more than 2 columns not working that above logic.

Comment: @user3106578: it works on as many columns as you want. see this update with 3 colmuns: http://jsfiddle.net/F3jRj/2/

Answer (score 0):

Your code is behaving correctly. Just that you need to clear all previously highlighted rows on "keyup" of input text first.

```
if (text.length > 1) {
grid.find('tr:has(td)').css({ background: "" });
grid.find('tr').show();
......rest of your code.......
```

Comment: if more than 2 columns not working that above logic.